# Kubernetes - Unable to cordon the node

Tags: kubernetes

We have on-prem cluster. I am trying to cordon a node using `kubectl cordon <node>` the command is successful, but when I am running command `kubectl get nodes` I see nodes is still ready. Where should I check next?

I didnt find any error in api-server. Where should I check? Etcd logs (how to check them) ? Scheduler?

Comment: Should this question be asked in sserverfault?

Comment: please check my below comments

Comment: this question could be further improved by adding either the full message one get in the terminal  after issuing the command `kubectl cordon <node>` or by sharing a screenshot. Cordoning a node does not make it  **"unready"**, it makes it unschedulable whilst making sure existing pods running on it do not get evicted. Ready is ok, it is the rest of the message that is important i.e. schedulable or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [doc](https://cast.ai/blog/kubernetes-cordon-how-it-works-and-when-to-use-it/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Cordoning%20a%20node,be%20added%20to%20your%20cluster.&text=The%20existing%20pods%20on%20this,this%20and%20will%20remain%20accessible.) written by Laurent Gil cordoning a node will have two steps to complete the process:

Cordoning a node means making the node unschedulable. This means that this node cannot accommodate any more pods as long as it is marked as unschedulable.

> **Step :1** To place a cordon around a named node, use this command:
>
> ```
> kubectl cordon my-node
> ```
>
> The existing pods on this node won’t be affected by this and will
> remain accessible.   Want to check which nodes are cordoned off at the
> moment? Use the get nodes command:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl get nodes
> ```
>
> **Step :2** To empty the node from the remaining pods, you need to drain it. This process evicts the pods so they can be rescheduled to
> other nodes in your cluster. You can gracefully terminate pods before
> forcing them to be removed from the node you’re planning to drain.
>
> To start the drain procedure, run the kubectl drain command,
> specifying the name of the node you’re draining:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl drain node
> ```
>
> First, we have Kubernetes cordoning – it cordons the node if you
> haven’t done that manually. Next, it evicts running pods (even if
> there is no space to reschedule them). Once the node is empty, you can
> shut it down or destroy it. The cordon assures that no new workloads
> can be scheduled on this node once the drain is completed.
>
> **Automate Kubernetes node cordoning and draining**: Changing the compute resources your nodes run on manually quickly becomes
> time-consuming if you’re dealing with many nodes. You can let CAST AI
> do the job and do the node cordoning and draining for you as part of
> its automated optimization mechanisms.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I do understand what is cordoning and draining. Right now my problem is that node is not entering in uncshcedulable state when I am running the command, and I need to troubleshoot the issue, so I am asking what all things I need to look for cordoning it.

Comment: Check what version of Kubernetes your cluster's control plane is running, and then check what version of Kubernetes your cluster's node pools are running. If any of the cluster's node pools are more than two minor versions older than the control plane, this might be causing issues with your cluster.

Comment: The Kubernetes version and version skew support policy guarantees that control planes are compatible with nodes up to two minor versions older than the control plane. For example, Kubernetes 1.19 control planes are compatible with Kubernetes 1.19, 1.18, and 1.17 nodes. To resolve this issue, manually upgrade the node pool version to a version that is compatible with the control plane.

Comment: If you are concerned about the upgrade process causing disruption to workloads running on the affected nodes, follow the steps in the Migrating the workloads section of the Migrating workloads to different machine types [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool#step_4_migrate_the_workloads). These steps let you migrate gracefully by creating a new node pool and then cordoning and draining the old node pool.

Comment: 1,2.  We started facing issue when our Control plane and nodes were on 1.21. I recently upgraded them to 1.23, it didnt fix the issue I had used  taints to avoid workload scheduling during the upgrade. but cordoning still do not work.  
`kubectl cordon <node>` this command does not seems to have any impact on the cluster, earlier it used to work.
 3. We are using on-prem k8s cluster, there is no concept of node pool in it.